# Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React/Redux application and it's using a big amount of data, when I try to load it in Redux I get this warning:

> Application state or actions payloads are too large making Redux
> DevTools serialization slow and consuming a lot of memory. See
> https://git.io/fpcP5 on how to configure it.

And the Navigator crashes. Any help please to solve it?